# Como imprimir somente os 5 primeiros caracteres?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preciso que seja exibido até no máximo 5 caracteres do conteúdo de cada célula da tabela em uma resolução específica. Não sei se existe algum `Pseudo Elemento` que faça o que eu preciso, algo como:

### Exemplo:

```
@media (max-width: 548px) {
    p:only-five-letters {
        content: IMPRIME;
    }
}
```

### Saída exemplo:

```
IMPRI
```

Conforme o `Snippet` abaixo, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso no CSS, ou algum script que faça isso?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<strong>Como está:</strong>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> OSe </td>
    <td> Status </td>
    <td> Garantia </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75553 </td>
    <td> Expedido </td>
    <td> Aprovada </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75552 </td>
    <td> Cancelado </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75551 </td>
    <td> Analise </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<strong>Como eu preciso:</strong>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> OSe </td>
    <td> Statu </td>
    <td> Garan </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75553 </td>
    <td> Exped </td>
    <td> Aprov </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75552 </td>
    <td> Cance </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75551 </td>
    <td> Anali </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você terá que trazer esses dados já tratados para o seu `html` ou através de um `js` você vai percorrer todos os elementos da sua `table` e reduzir a quantidade de caracteres para 5

Comment: Tipo, tenho eles no meu banco de dados, então na hora de montar a tabela eu percorro cada um deles e na hora de imprimir eu imprimo somente os cinco primeiros caracteres ?

Comment: isso mesmo, no caso vc vai precisar do conteúdo completo deles depois?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, preciso que seja feito isso somente quando estiver em uma resolução específica

Comment: Sim, por isso preciso que seja exibido somente 5 caracteres deles, quando estiverem em uma resolução específica, fazendo com que eles se acomodem direitinho na tela.

Comment: agora sim, o ideal é que vc faça isso através de um `js`, e além disso vc salve seus valores originais em um atributo `data`, para poder retornar o valor original caso a resolução volte ao normal, no momento n tenho como te ajudar no código, mas se ninguém responder até mais tarde eu te ajudo

Comment: Ao invés de limitar os caracteres já tentou limitar o tamanho da célula usando `max-width`. Não ficaria 100% mas seria mais prático do que percorrer todos os valores para limitá-los um a um

Comment: Vou tentar fazer com `JS`, mas você diz, limitar a largura de cada coluna?

Comment: No caso limitaria o tamanho de cada célula, a ponto que coubesse em média 5 caracteres

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar aplicar ! Valeu !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pode-se usar o `ch`

```css
.limit {
  max-width: 5.8ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="limit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum deserunt ad repellendus libero iste deleniti sequi illo suscipit maxime harum vitae, minus a beatae mollitia alias! Quo sint nemo neque.</div>
```

---

A unidade `ch`- **character unit** ou **unidade-caractere** em português - é definida como sendo a **medida avançada** da largura do caractere zero `0`.

É mais usada para braile, porém, abre espaços para outras situações, como essa.

#### Update

Você pode usar números decimais no tamanho. Coloquei `5.8ch` e não ficou cortado. É que isso depende do tamanho de 1 caracter. Você tem que saber o tamanho real dele. Não sei se tem uma função em JS ou CSS que faça isso.

Comment: Utilizando do `CH`, alcanço o que eu queria (em partes), porém, fica visivelmente feio, pois fica aparecendo as letras cortadas, mas obrigado por sua contribuição!

Comment: @MarcosHenzel fique tranquilo. Veja o que é melhor para vós mecê. Mas eu fiz uma alteração, caso queira ver.

Comment: Sim, eu compreendo, mas se for utilizar fontes de tamanhos diferentes nesses campos onde será "cortado", acredito que não terá a mesma funcionalidade que do modo em que foi passado na resposta acima, utilizando o `slice` e/ou o `substr` do `JS`.

Comment: A resposta acima é mais dinâmica, funciona para qualquer jeito sem escrever muito.

Answer (score 3):

Uma string é um array de caracteres em javascript, então é possível obter um range de caracteres desse array usando [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

**Exemplo:**

```js
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (i = 0 ; i < tds.length ; i++){
  tds[i].innerHTML = (tds[i].innerHTML).slice(0,6);
}
```

```css
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<strong>Como está:</strong>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> OSe </td>
    <td> Status </td>
    <td> Garantia </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75553 </td>
    <td> Expedido </td>
    <td> Aprovada </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75552 </td>
    <td> Cancelado </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75551 </td>
    <td> Analise </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<strong>Como eu preciso:</strong>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> OSe </td>
    <td> Statu </td>
    <td> Garan </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75553 </td>
    <td> Exped </td>
    <td> Aprov </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75552 </td>
    <td> Cance </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75551 </td>
    <td> Anali </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Dessa forma é possível recortar (limitar) a quantidade de caracteres.

***Editado:***

### Solução:

*Dessa forma é impresso os 5 primeiros caracteres que era preciso em cada coluna da tabela, quando fosse alterado para uma resolução específica*

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
window.onresize = function() {
    var largura = screen.width;
    var altura = screen.height;

    if (largura <= 320 && altura <= 480) {
        for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
// armazeno localmente em uma variável os valores originais do td
            localStorage.setItem('td' + i, td[i].innerHTML);
            td[i].innerHTML = (td[i].innerHTML).slice(0,6);
        }
    }
    if (largura <= 480 && altura <= 320) {
        for (a = 0; a < td.length; a++) {
// recupero os valores originais dos td's
            td[a].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('td' + a);
        }
    } else {
      for (b = 0; b < td.length; b++) {
// esvazio a variável local que foi criada
            Storage.removeItem('td' + b);
        }
    }
};
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<br><strong>Solução</strong>:
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> OSe </td>
    <td> Status </td>
    <td> Garantia </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75553 </td>
    <td> Expedido </td>
    <td> Aprovada </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75552 </td>
    <td> Cancelado </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 75551 </td>
    <td> Analise </td>
    <td> Não </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ta aparecendo Error: { "message": "SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer", "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js", "lineno": 78, "colno": 9 }

Comment: no caso ele precisa também dos valores originais, para voltar ao normal dependendo da resolução no momento que o usuário esteja visualizando o conteudo

Comment: @MarcosHenzel, talvez tenha sido problema momentâneo do snippet do stack, aqui está funcionando..

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida, o ponto da resposta é a utilização do slice, é um exemplo. Os elementos que irá ser selecionados depende fica a critério do seletor.

Comment: Certo @LucasCosta obrigado, vou ver aqui se consigo aplicar ao meu código!

Comment: Agora eu vi a edição onde você precisa disso somente em uma certa resolução @MarcosHenzel

Comment: @LucasCosta, depois de estudar um pouco sobre o método `slice`, `substr`, eu percebi que a sua resposta estava exatamente como eu queria, porém faltou apenas os parenteses de abertura `(` e de fechamento `)` na hora de atribuir o valor à variável dentro do `for`, ficando assim: `(tds[i].innerHTML).slice(0,6);` 

E o erro que estava dando era por causa do uso do `let` no `for`, removi o mesmo e o código funcionou perfeitamente.

Então utilizei dos métodos do `JS` para detectar a troca de resolução e apliquei o seu cod! 

Obrigado @LucasCosta, `That's the right response for this question!`